# Can mod_rewrite [P]roxy to an HTTPS url when the inbound request URL is HTTP?

Tags: mod-rewrite, http, reverse-proxy, https

I have a host (IIS6, running an implementation of mod_rewrite for windows, by a co called Micronovae. It works well) that has a site at http://some.host.com

I also have another host (on Microsoft azure) that has a site at https://secure.otherhost.com

Currently I have a mod_rewrite ruleset thus:

```
#visitor to some.host.com is transparently proxied to new site at secure.otherhost.com
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} some\.host\.com [NC]
ReWriteRule (.*) https://secure.otherhost.com$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

I know the rules work (though I've set logging options and the darn thing doesn't seem to log to where it should) because if I make it an [R] rule instead of a [P] rule, then the browser receives a redirect and goes to secure.otherhost.com on HTTPS just fine

But.. If I enable [P]roxy mode instead, I simply get a 404 error when I try to go to http://some.host.com

Can anyone give me a clue? Can the server do an HTTPS conversation with the foreign server, and then return the results to my client browser over HTTP?